# List object concatenation returns TypeError

Tags: python

So I'm creating a method which is used to concatenate lists of: integers, strings and lists.

Here is my method:

```
def concat(l):
    if(l):
        if(type(l[0]) is int):
            return l[0] + concat(l[1:])
        else:
            return l[0] + concat(l[1:])
    else:
        return l
```

However when I run it on my example code:

```
print("Integer Concat: " + str(concat([1,2,5])))
print("String Concat: " + str(concat(["1", "2", "5"])))
print("List Concat: " + concat([[1], [2,5]]))
```

It returns this error:

```
Integer Concat: []

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path-omitted", line x, in <module>
    print("String Concat: " + str(concat(["1", "2", "3", "10"])))
File "path-omitted", line x, in concat
    return list[0] + concat(list[1:])
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Not only do i get the error, but my integers in the list aren't summing up together as they should! Thanks :)

Comment: list[1:] is a list not string. If you want to concatenate an item in string try mentioning the index refers to that item explicitly. Or you can convert every item in list to string with a loop or list comprehension. like
strList = [str(x) for x in listone]

Comment: @cutteeth either way, the function i wrote still doesn't take into account my integer list.